# Which underlayment, if any, between 5" pine boards, and subfloor with radiant heat?

Tags: hardwood-floor, underlayment, tongue-and-groove

Seems to be a lot of differing opinions on this. I get that having something between the two can offer less squeaking, some noise abatement and depending on material - a vapor barrier which I may or may not need.

Waxed paper? Paper with tar-infused? Some Tyvek-like material? Nothing?

Help would be greatly appreciated. Some professionals I've talked to seem like they're just trying to upsell me on the latest/greatest Microban-infused super layer stuff. Which leaves me with a wide variety of answers.

Comment: You might want to add what kind of radiant heat and if you know approximately what temperature you will be running the heat.

Comment: Not sure of the kind of radiant heat - other than it's liquid running through lines in varying patterns. I'm assuming it's water in the line - maybe some kind of antifreeze? Will investigate once I get access to the house again.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. You want the wood to breathe & there are plenty of 100+ year old houses to prove & approve this "method". If you're gluing & face nailing the boards, then **forget the nails**. Screw down the subfloor & then Finish Screw down the finish floor. You'll never have a squeak & the floor will always be solid.

Comment: Contractor said he'll be stapling - I'm assuming it's a power tool of sorts. I'm going to talk to him again today to verify as it seems everyone agrees that there should also be glue. So if there's glue - doesn't that make putting paper down pointless?

Comment: Oh, that's too bad. But, it'll be quiet & problem free for 10-months or 10-years...hopefully the latter. No paper needed, it would just be for a vapor barrier & unless it was a floating floor you wouldn't want any kind of padding, that would be staple squeak city. The glue will still breathe & allow movement, but does also work below or above a paper or underlayment.

Comment: Is nailing better? Longer lasting?

We did this same wood in our current house - and it was nailed - no glue. 3 years in now - still solid - though - a bit squeaky. 

I don't have access to the same contractor that lead, and I assisted, on the last install - so I'm working with the best guy I can find (and afford) this time.

Comment: Nope nails & staples are just a lot quicker & easier. That's why I was hoping you were doing it yourself. Finish Screws are the only way to go & they can't ever squeak. Nails & staples are the squeak sounds, they just slide in & out of their holes.